# Initializing a dynamic array of stl lists for a Hash Table (Separate Chaining)

Tags: c++, arrays, hash, stl, initialization

I am having a problem with my program throwing an exception when inserting data at specific index's of my array. I am using a hash table, and trying to use the STL list in an array of pointers to another class that contains the data.
Since this is a Hash Table, I'm avoiding using the vector class since the size of the array should be constant. (I know the initial size that I want)

MCVE (For you) :

```
    #ifndef HASHTABLE_H
    #define HASHTABLE_H

    #include <list>
    #include <cstring>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    template <typename T1>
    class HashTable
    {
      public:
           HashTable();
           void Insert(T1 var)
           int FindPrime(int);
           int HashFunction(string);
      private:
           int prime;
           list<T1> *List;
           int LF;
    }
    #endif

template <typename T1>
HashTable<T1>::HashTable()
{
  List[i] = list<T1>();
}

template <typename T1>
int HashTable<T1>::FindPrime(int num)
{
    bool isNotPrime = false;
    for (int i=num; i < num + 25; ++i)
    {
       for (int j=2; j<i; ++j)
        {
            if (i % j == 0)
                {
                    isNotPrime = true;
                }
        }

        if (isNotPrime == false)
            {
                    prime = i;
                    return prime;
                    break;
            }

        isNotPrime = false;
    }
        prime = num;
        return prime;
    }
    template <typename T1>
long HashTable<T1>::HashFunction(string key)
{
    long numkey = 0;    
    char word[1000];
    strcpy(word,key.c_str());
    word[sizeof(word) - 1] = NULL;              //Ensure null is at last index of word
    for(int i = 0; word[i] != NULL; ++i)
    {
        numkey = numkey + (word[i] * 101 + word[i]);
    }
    numkey = numkey % prime;
    return numkey;


}
    template <typename T1>
    void HashTable<T1>::Insert(T1 var)
    {
        int index = HashFunction(var -> getKey());
        List[index].push_front(var);
        ++LF;
        cout << "Load Factor: " << LF << endl << endl;
    }
```

from a seperate class that is determining what to do with the data:

```
file >> num;
hash.FindPrime(num);
file >> letter; // Get letter from file so we know what to do
    if(letter == 'D' || letter == 'd')  //If the letter is D, then add a new DNA Node with corresponding data to the STL List
        {   
            file >> Label >> ID >> Seq >> Length >> Index;
            cout << "Note: Adding " << Label << " ..." << endl << endl;
            Sequence* ptr = new DNA(Label, ID, Seq, Length, Index);
            hash.Insert(ptr);
            ptr = NULL;
            delete ptr;
        }
```

Sequence Class is the base class for Several inherited classes (DNA is one of them)

Comment: I don't understand why you don't just use a `std::vector<std::list<T1>>` and set the initial size of your vector to the prime you desire. The result would be a table of empty lists, which would seem desirable considering you avoid all the potential problems of manually managing the memory yourself (of course, `std::unordered_map<>` would solve this directly, but it seems more of an exercise than a target for production code). If your still set on the masochistic goal of manual memory management, R.Sahu seems to have an answer for you.

Comment: @WhozCraig I could, but I prefer to try and understand the underlying fundamentals instead of always relying on a standard library to do it for me. I coded a linked list myself for a previous project before using the STL list, and I understood it a whole lot better. I just prefer it this way for learning.

Answer (score 1):

Type of `List[i]` is `list<T1>`. That's why the compiler doesn't allow you to use:

```
List[i] = new list<T1>;
// Trying to assign a list<T1>* to a list<T1>.
```

You can use

```
List[i] = list<T1>();
```

or

```
list<T1>** List;
```

Comment: Ok, if i use the first one in my constructor, my program still throws the exception when trying to push_front. If I use the second one to declare the List, the compiler throws an error: error C2228: left of '.begin' must have class/struct/union
Is the problem with List[index].push_front(var);?? It's either an exception or a compilation error at that line with both. I still feel lost lol.

Comment: @DavidRutledge, can you post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? It's difficult to see the whole picture with bits and pieces of code.

Comment: @R Sahu Done! Sorry, I should have included those from the start, but figured it wouldnt have helped with the problem, but it might.

Comment: The posted code for the constructor is not compilable. I think you misunderstand what an MCVE is. It should be compilable and linkable.

Comment: @R Sahu  sorry again, I didn't understand. Hopefully my last edit is what you were trying to get at. Fixed it.